# How can I store the data for multiple objective in shortest path search in C++

Tags: c++, graph, shortest-path

I'm now working on the shortest path search in a graph with `N` nodes, and its edges have not only length but also other costs. In total, I have to consider four to seven costs for an edge. In the classical shortest path search written in C++, I use an array `int*` with size of `N` to store the cost at each node. But this does not work with this multiple objective graph as I need to store many intermedia data for each node because there are many objectives and it is not possible to decide which one is the best when the new edge is taken into consideration.

[image: example for costs]

For example, under this image. If I only consider cost in black, then it would be easy to say the cost is 3 from node 1 to node 2. If I consider both red and black costs, at node 2 I have to store (3,7) and (6,5) for the further search. In this case, for each node, the stored data is not at a fixed size, so `int*` does not work.
Maybe I should use `vector` to store the data for each node, but as I Googled, people say it's not a good idea to use `array` of `vector` to store the data. Then I thought `vector<vector<pairs <int, int>>>` is a possible solution, would it be too large if the graph is so big. If not so, would it be kind of waste computation because updates for data of each nodes are frequent during the search.
I wonder if there is a better way to store data during this process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the number of different weight types fix or variable? If it is fix you can define your own struct type e.g. `t_weights` and use `t_weights[]`. Or even more simple declare for each weight a separate `int[]`. If you need a variable number of weights per edge, you can use 2-dimensional arrays. And if performance is not your main concern but flexibility and stability you can also use `vector<vector<int>>`. Also it depends a little bit on the structure of the algorithm you want to implement. If you need further help, please share a minimal, reproducible code example!

Answer (score 0):

You already have the edge costs stored somewhere, probably in an edge class.  So there is no need to store another copy of the same data.

Store the index of each edge of the path as the path is built, and lookup the costs for each path edge index when required.

Comment: Yes, this would be a solution and get the answer to the traditional shortest path search. If a node has more than one pre-nodes, then the problem becomes more complex and in this way is still not possible to find the set of optimal paths.

Comment: @superDoge  Simply asserting "it is not possible" is insufficient. That is what is called a hand waving argument. We need a concrete detailed small problem illustrating your point.

Comment: In Dijkstra's shortest path search, the shortest path from O to D. The meaning of recording the pre-node of each node in the path is to track the shortest path. But in this problem, if we only record the pre-nodes, that would have at least two problems. (1) each node would have multiple pre-nodes that need to record because you cannot find the exact shortest path for two or more objectives. (2) Based on that, all nodes that lay on the possible shortest paths would be recorded, and for each path, we need to record sequence rather than record pre-nodes. The problem looks more complex now.

Comment: My word, you do like words!  Lets have some data and actual code.  A real sample problem to solve.